# Defining a font on a label breaks PDF generation

Tags: pdf, fonts, birt

In my Birt report (blank one with a single label containing the string "Test"), I'm trying to use a new font for a label.

That font was not bundled with Windows, so I installed it manually on my system.

As soon as I change the font of my label to this specific one, the PDF generation is broken: my browser gives me that error instead of displaying the PDF:

> "Caractères non autorisés dans un nom. Local\EWH-4196-0"

which I can translate in english to:

> "Unauthorized character in a name. Local\EWH-4196-0"

The number in the message always change at each PDF generation.

If I generate it to a PDF and try to open it with Adobe Acrobat Reader, I've got that message:

> Une erreur est survenue lors de l'ouverture de ce document. Une erreur est survenue à la lecture de ce document (129).

which in english is:

> There was an error processing a page. There was a problem reading this document(129)

I've tested to make Word export to PDF a .docx containing "Test" with this font and got no problem to open it with Adobe Reader.

I've created the question on [Birt dev forum](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/39080-defining-a-font-on-a-label-breaks-pdf-generation/) with the `.rptdesign` & problematic font (Canadian Penguin).

Comment: It seems like the backslash character causes the problem. So the question is: Where does the backslash come from? Maybe the font itself is causing the problem. Can you try with a different font (e.g. Tahoma)?

Comment: I only have the label "Test" in my report... With another font I've got no problem. But the font I've selected seems OK: in word or any other software, I've got no problem to use it... it seems that birts generates me a wrong PDF...

Comment: do you see more information in the debug info of BIRT? Perhaps you can pinpoint the problem a bit more. What type of font is it?

Comment: The symptoms indicate that probably your font is corrupted, probably one of the font names stored inside the font violates some specification, if I should guess. BTW just because the font seems to work with other software does NOT necessarily imply that the font is OK!

Comment: Actually, I've just tried to create a word document with the same "Test" text using the problematic font, then ask Word to export it as PDF, and all went OK: the PDF file generated by Word can be opened... so I don't think my font is corrupted, but I think it's more like if Birt couldn't generate correct PDF with this specific font... perhaps a bug in Birt ?

Comment: What is the name of this font?

Comment: I've updated my question to link to my [question on Birt dev forum](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/39080-defining-a-font-on-a-label-breaks-pdf-generation/) which includes the problematic font & `.rptdesign`.